# TCL/TK: Is it possible to create a new folder or edit a folder in the "tk_getSaveFile" pop-up view?

Tags: tk-toolkit, tcltk

[image]

Is it possible to create a new folder or edit a folder in the "tk_getSaveFile" pop-up view? Or, is there any package that supports this? thanks